# udev rule for cdma modem is not working

Tags: usb-modem, udev

The udev rule i've written for CDMA modem is

```
SUBSYSTEM=="tty", ATTRS{bInterfaceNumber}=="00", ATTRS{bNumEndpoints}=="03", ATTRS{product}=="ZTE CDMA Tech", ACTION=="add", SYMLINK+="CDMAModem"
```

and

```
$ sudo udevadm info -a -p $(sudo udevadm info -q path -n /dev/ttyUSB0)

Udevadm info starts with the device specified by the devpath and then
walks up the chain of parent devices. It prints for every device
found, all possible attributes in the udev rules key format.
A rule to match, can be composed by the attributes of the device
and the attributes from one single parent device.

  looking at device '/devices/ocp.2/47400000.usb/musb-hdrc.1.auto/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4.3/1-1.4.3:1.0/ttyUSB0/tty/ttyUSB0':
    KERNEL=="ttyUSB0"
    SUBSYSTEM=="tty"
    DRIVER==""

  looking at parent device '/devices/ocp.2/47400000.usb/musb-hdrc.1.auto/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4.3/1-1.4.3:1.0/ttyUSB0':
    KERNELS=="ttyUSB0"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb-serial"
    DRIVERS=="option1"
    ATTRS{port_number}=="0"

  looking at parent device '/devices/ocp.2/47400000.usb/musb-hdrc.1.auto/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4.3/1-1.4.3:1.0':
    KERNELS=="1-1.4.3:1.0"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="option"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceClass}=="ff"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceSubClass}=="ff"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceProtocol}=="ff"
    ATTRS{bNumEndpoints}=="03"
    ATTRS{supports_autosuspend}=="1"
    ATTRS{bAlternateSetting}==" 0"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceNumber}=="00"
    ATTRS{interface}=="Data Interface"

  looking at parent device '/devices/ocp.2/47400000.usb/musb-hdrc.1.auto/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4.3':
    KERNELS=="1-1.4.3"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="usb"
    ATTRS{bDeviceSubClass}=="00"
    ATTRS{bDeviceProtocol}=="00"
    ATTRS{devpath}=="1.4.3"
    ATTRS{idVendor}=="19d2"
    ATTRS{speed}=="12"
    ATTRS{bNumInterfaces}==" 6"
    ATTRS{bConfigurationValue}=="1"
    ATTRS{bMaxPacketSize0}=="64"
    ATTRS{busnum}=="1"
    ATTRS{devnum}=="6"
    ATTRS{configuration}==""
    ATTRS{bMaxPower}=="500mA"
    ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
    ATTRS{bmAttributes}=="a0"
    ATTRS{bNumConfigurations}=="1"
    ATTRS{maxchild}=="0"
    ATTRS{bcdDevice}=="0000"
    ATTRS{avoid_reset_quirk}=="0"
    ATTRS{quirks}=="0x0"
    ATTRS{version}==" 1.10"
    ATTRS{urbnum}=="3895"
    ATTRS{ltm_capable}=="no"
    ATTRS{manufacturer}=="ZTE, Incorporated"
    ATTRS{removable}=="unknown"
    ATTRS{idProduct}=="fff1"
    ATTRS{bDeviceClass}=="00"
    ATTRS{product}=="ZTE CDMA Tech"

  looking at parent device '/devices/ocp.2/47400000.usb/musb-hdrc.1.auto/usb1/1-1/1-1.4':
    KERNELS=="1-1.4"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="usb"
    ATTRS{bDeviceSubClass}=="00"
    ATTRS{bDeviceProtocol}=="01"
    ATTRS{devpath}=="1.4"
    ATTRS{idVendor}=="05e3"
    ATTRS{speed}=="480"
    ATTRS{bNumInterfaces}==" 1"
    ATTRS{bConfigurationValue}=="1"
    ATTRS{bMaxPacketSize0}=="64"
    ATTRS{busnum}=="1"
    ATTRS{devnum}=="5"
    ATTRS{configuration}==""
    ATTRS{bMaxPower}=="100mA"
    ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
    ATTRS{bmAttributes}=="e0"
    ATTRS{bNumConfigurations}=="1"
    ATTRS{maxchild}=="4"
    ATTRS{bcdDevice}=="7764"
    ATTRS{avoid_reset_quirk}=="0"
    ATTRS{quirks}=="0x0"
    ATTRS{version}==" 2.00"
    ATTRS{urbnum}=="29"
    ATTRS{ltm_capable}=="no"
    ATTRS{removable}=="unknown"
    ATTRS{idProduct}=="0608"
    ATTRS{bDeviceClass}=="09"
    ATTRS{product}=="USB2.0 Hub"

  looking at parent device '/devices/ocp.2/47400000.usb/musb-hdrc.1.auto/usb1/1-1':
    KERNELS=="1-1"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="usb"
    ATTRS{bDeviceSubClass}=="00"
    ATTRS{bDeviceProtocol}=="01"
    ATTRS{devpath}=="1"
    ATTRS{idVendor}=="05e3"
    ATTRS{speed}=="480"
    ATTRS{bNumInterfaces}==" 1"
    ATTRS{bConfigurationValue}=="1"
    ATTRS{bMaxPacketSize0}=="64"
    ATTRS{busnum}=="1"
    ATTRS{devnum}=="2"
    ATTRS{configuration}==""
    ATTRS{bMaxPower}=="100mA"
    ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
    ATTRS{bmAttributes}=="e0"
    ATTRS{bNumConfigurations}=="1"
    ATTRS{maxchild}=="4"
    ATTRS{bcdDevice}=="7764"
    ATTRS{avoid_reset_quirk}=="0"
    ATTRS{quirks}=="0x0"
    ATTRS{version}==" 2.00"
    ATTRS{urbnum}=="49"
    ATTRS{ltm_capable}=="no"
    ATTRS{removable}=="unknown"
    ATTRS{idProduct}=="0608"
    ATTRS{bDeviceClass}=="09"
    ATTRS{product}=="USB2.0 Hub"

  looking at parent device '/devices/ocp.2/47400000.usb/musb-hdrc.1.auto/usb1':
    KERNELS=="usb1"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="usb"
    ATTRS{bDeviceSubClass}=="00"
    ATTRS{bDeviceProtocol}=="01"
    ATTRS{devpath}=="0"
    ATTRS{idVendor}=="1d6b"
    ATTRS{speed}=="480"
    ATTRS{bNumInterfaces}==" 1"
    ATTRS{bConfigurationValue}=="1"
    ATTRS{bMaxPacketSize0}=="64"
    ATTRS{authorized_default}=="1"
    ATTRS{busnum}=="1"
    ATTRS{devnum}=="1"
    ATTRS{configuration}==""
    ATTRS{bMaxPower}=="  0mA"
    ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
    ATTRS{bmAttributes}=="e0"
    ATTRS{bNumConfigurations}=="1"
    ATTRS{maxchild}=="1"
    ATTRS{bcdDevice}=="0308"
    ATTRS{avoid_reset_quirk}=="0"
    ATTRS{quirks}=="0x0"
    ATTRS{serial}=="musb-hdrc.1.auto"
    ATTRS{version}==" 2.00"
    ATTRS{urbnum}=="28"
    ATTRS{ltm_capable}=="no"
    ATTRS{manufacturer}=="Linux 3.8.13-bone21 musb-hcd"
    ATTRS{removable}=="unknown"
    ATTRS{idProduct}=="0002"
    ATTRS{bDeviceClass}=="09"
    ATTRS{product}=="MUSB HDRC host driver"

  looking at parent device '/devices/ocp.2/47400000.usb/musb-hdrc.1.auto':
    KERNELS=="musb-hdrc.1.auto"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="platform"
    DRIVERS=="musb-hdrc"
    ATTRS{mode}=="b_peripheral"
    ATTRS{vbus}=="Vbus off, timeout 1100 msec"

  looking at parent device '/devices/ocp.2/47400000.usb':
    KERNELS=="47400000.usb"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="platform"
    DRIVERS=="musb-dsps"

  looking at parent device '/devices/ocp.2':
    KERNELS=="ocp.2"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="platform"
    DRIVERS==""
```

where did i go wrong? I don get `/dev/CDMAModem` when i plug in the modem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
KERNEL=="ttyUSB[0-9]*", SUBSYSTEM=="tty", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ACTION=="add", ATTRS{bInterfaceNumber}=="00", ATTRS{bNumEndpoints}=="03", ATTRS{product}=="ZTE CDMA Tech", SYMLINK+="CDMAModem"
```

`SYMLINK` needs device name match `KERNEL==` and `SUBSYSTEMS` for `ATTRS`.  Might actually work without `SUBSYSTEM` and/or `SUBSYSTEMS`....  Moved `ACTION` too.

Comment: what do you say about the answer I posted at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17881108/udev-rule-for-cdma-modem-is-not-working#answer-17885189 ?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ENV{.LOCAL_ifNum}="$attr{bInterfaceNumber}"
SUBSYSTEM=="tty", ATTRS{idVendor}=="1234", ATTRS{idProduct}=="5678", SYMLINK+="your_device%E{.LOCAL_ifNum}"
```